# how to check array is sorted or not using recursion in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to write one function which give me `array is sorted or not`.if it sorted then return `true` else `false` .I want to do this using `recursion`

```
n = [1, 2, 3]
function isSorted(arr, n) {
    if (n > arr.length || n ==0) {
        return false
    }

    if (arr[n] < arr[n-1]) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
    return isSorted(arr,n-1)
}

console.log(isSorted(n,n.length-1))
```

currently it is giving me `false` but expected `true`

update

```
function isSorted(arr, n) {
    if (n ==0 || n ==1) {
        return false
    }

    if (arr[n] < arr[n-1]) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
    return isSorted(arr,n-1)
}

console.log(isSorted(n,n.length-1))
```

Comment: `if (n < arr.length /* ... */ )` `return false`, `isSorted(n,n.length-1)` - any debugger and stepping through just three lines would tell you the first issue... Note: i am not saying, that this is the only issue, i stopped reading there

Comment: ohh sorry ...!! wait checking

Comment: please check update ..it work correctly

Comment: Now you have an `else return true`, so your function ALWAYS returns either `false` or `true` from that `if`, without ever doing any recursive calls (the tailcall is unreachable code, which any decent IDE should mark). Please start working in a proper environment, it will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: ohh great got it will try on more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create new array objects (as would occur when using `slice`). You can just recursively iterate through the original array, as shown by the `check` function:

```js
function isSorted(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  var last = arr.length - 1;
  return (function check() {
    return (i >= last) || (arr[i] <= arr[++i] && check());
  })();
}

console.log(isSorted([1, 2, 3 ]))
console.log(isSorted([1, 1, 1 ]))
console.log(isSorted([0]))
console.log(isSorted([]))
console.log(isSorted([1, 4, 3 ]))
console.log(isSorted([10, 5]))
console.log(isSorted([3, 5, 0]))
```

Comment: Yeah, this is undoubtedly going to be more efficient (probably by a wide margin). On the other hand, if efficiency is the goal here, we wouldn't be writing a recursive function in the first place.

Comment: Definitely. But the Question stipulates that recursion MUST be used. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the base case: if an array is length 1 or 0, then it's sorted.

Otherwise, it's only sorted if the first element is less than or equal to the second and the rest of the array is also sorted. In code, that might look like:

```js
function isSorted(arr) {
   return arr.length <= 1
   ? true
   : arr[0] <= arr[1] && isSorted(arr.slice(1))
}

console.log(isSorted([1, 2, 3 ]))
console.log(isSorted([1, 1, 1 ]))
console.log(isSorted([0]))
console.log(isSorted([1, 4, 3 ]))
```

Comment: @marks thanks for answering ..see my update question I am able to check .is it correct approch.I know your answer is correct

Comment: @user944513, no, your base case is not correct. An array of length 1 **is** sorted, but you're returning false in the base case.

Comment: I think you could also use `||` here: `return arr.length <= 1 || arr[0] <= arr[1] && isSorted(arr.slice(1))` instead of a ternary, but that might be harder to read/understand

Comment: Yeah, @NickParsons, I think you are correct…that would work.